# Dynamically run "ansible-galaxy install -r requirement.yml -p roles/" as a prerequisite before running a role

Tags: ansible, roles

I'm trying to get the following Ansible playbook to work but cannot figure out how to tell Ansible to either:

- ignore a check for existence of a role
- run a ansible-galaxy command to automatically load role before using it

Here's my code:

```
- name: Install prerequisite roles
  hosts: all
  become: no

  tasks:
    - name: run ansible galaxy
      local_action: command ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml -p roles/

- name: Install Oracle Java
  hosts: tomcat-servers:ss-servers:ns-servers:ld-servers
  become: yes

  roles:
    - raltd-jdk
```

I tried doing the above using `pre_tasks` as well and that didn't work either. My `requirements.yml` is simply this:

```
- src: git@gitserver.mydom.com:ansible/raltd-jdk.git
  scm: git
```

I'm getting this error:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inv/myinventory raltd-jdk.yml
 ERROR! the role 'raltd-jdk' was not found in /path/to/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles:/path/to/ansible

 The error appears to have been in '/path/to/ansible/raltd-jdk.yml': line 16, column 7, but may
 be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

 The offending line appears to be:

   roles:
       - raltd-jdk
             ^ here
```

#### References

- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22508

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received the following response from the Ansible dev team.

> @slmingol this particular error is by design. Roles and tasks are
>   preloaded before any of them are executed. We have ongoing proposals
>   that tackle this problem from different angles, but none of them have
>   yet to be accepted or written.

He also referenced this proposal: [Proposal: Auto Install Ansible Roles](https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/7)

> To use the latest (or even a specific) version of a playbook with the
>   appropriate roles, the following steps are typically required:
>
> ```
> git pull upstream branch
> ansible-galaxy install -r path/to/rolesfile.yml -p path/to/rolesdir -f
> ansible-playbook run-the-playbook.yml
> ```
>
> The most likely step in this process to be forgotten is the middle
>   step. While we can improve processes and documentation to try and
>   ensure that this step is not skipped, we can improve ansible-playbook
>   so that the step is not required.

So it would appear this isn't possible until this proposal gets implemented.

#### References

- https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/7

Comment: to clarify i'll add some semicolons: git pull upstream branch;  ansible-galaxy install -r path/to/rolesfile.yml -p path/to/rolesdir -f; ansible-playbook
run-the-playbook.yml

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the requirements.yml too, and then using [include_role](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html) to run them immediately.

`include*` statements are [processed as they are encountered](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_reuse_includes.html#includes-vs-imports).

```
- name: Get required roles with ansible galaxy
  local_action: command ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml -p roles/

- name: Install some.role
  include_role: 
    name: some.role
```